# How to pivot this tables using entity framework linq

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, pivot

My table structure is here

`Product` table (Repo.Products)
`ID`  `ProductName`
`02`  `Computer`

`Property` table (Repo.Properties)

`ID`  `PropertyName`
`03`  `CPU`
`04`  `RAM`

`Product Property` table (Repo.ProductProperties)
`ID`  `ProductID` `PropertyID` `Value`
`01`  `02`        `03`        `1300`
`02`  `02`        `04` `1024`

My target output is
`Product Name` `CPU` `RAM`
`Computer` `1300` `1024`

How to do using Entity Framework 4.0 ?